# can't find method java

Tags: class, methods, public

So I run the following program and my cmd prompt gives me an error saying that the getDescriptions() method is not found in the DataElements class. I'm sure there's a simple solution but I'm just stuck. Here's the DataElements class:

```
import java.io.*;

public class DataElements
{
File file;

private int columns;

private int row;

private int length;

private String name;

private String type;

private int position;

private String[] descriptions;


public File getFile(){
    return file;
}

public void setFile(File f){
    file = f;
}

public int getColumns(){
    return columns;
}

public void setColumns(int c){
    columns = c;
}

public int getRow(){
    return row;
}

public void setRow(int r){
    row = r;
}

public int getLength(){
    return length;
}

public void setLength(int l){
    length = l;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setName(String n){
    name = n;
}

public String getType(){
    return type;
}

public void setType(String t){
    type = t;
}

public int getPosition(){
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(int p){
    position = p;
}

public String[] getDescriptions(){
    return description;
}

public void setDescriptions(String[] d){
    description = d;
}
}
```

And here's the main method. If you need the CMSReader class let me know, but the problem seems to be stuck in these two classes

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Project2{
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean fileParsed = false;
    String inFile;
    String outFile;


    if(args.length != 1){
        System.out.println("Error. Enter one argument: the file that needs to be parsed.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));

    DataElements storage = new DataElements();

    CMSReader reader = new CMSReader(scan,storage);


    reader.scanTopData();

    System.out.println("Input File - " + storage.getName());
    System.out.println("Output File - ");//*************Look at this*********************
    System.out.println("Number of Variables - " + storage.getColumns());
    System.out.println("Number of Records - " + storage.getRow());
    System.out.println("Record Length - " + storage.getLength());
    System.out.println("Variable information:");

    reader.scanVariableData();

    String[] variableData = storage.getDescriptions();

    for(int i = 0; i < variableData.length ; i++){
        System.out.println(variableData[i]);
    }
}
}
```

I appreciate any help. Like I said, I'm sure it's something dumb but I've been looking at this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `description` is not declared in your `DataElements` class, which is why `DataElements` file cannot compile, and my guess is that you have an older compiled version (.class file) of `DataElements` which does not contain that method.

**Recommendation**:
Start working with a good IDE (IntelliJ is my personal favorite, but Eclipse and Netbeans are also good options). A good IDE, on top of all other goodies it provides, will highlight such issues in a way you won't miss.